# Like query on column of type enum in JPA

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I would like to do a `like` query on an enum column as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, String> 
{
  @Query("SELECT u FROM Student u WHERE u.house LIKE :namePrefix% ")
  Page<Student> getStudentWithMatchingHouseNamePrefix(@Param("namePrefix")
                                                                   String namePrefix,
                                                               Pageable pageable);
}
```

`Student` entity is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @NotNull
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(name = "house", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private House house;
  ...
}
```

I cannot understand how can I write the query without modifying underlying entity.

**EDIT**

Now I am writing the query as follows:

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM Student u WHERE CONCAT(u.house,'') LIKE :namePrefix%")
```

But even after house having multiple entries, I am getting empty list for all queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using concat

```
SELECT u.* FROM Student u WHERE u.house LIKE concat(:namePrefix,'%')
```

Comment: thanks for your response. This was not working, was getting an exception. I had to modify this slightly to get rid of this exception. Now I am getting empty list for all queries as I mentioned in OP.

Comment: seems .. weird  .. update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..